# fancybox.open width doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Can anyone explain why the width isn't being respected?

```
$.fancybox.open(
    ['#notifications'],
    {
        width : '400',
        closeBtn : false, 
        helpers : {
            overlay : {closeClick: false}
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: because Boolean and integer values go without quotes so it should be `width : 400,`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `autoDimensions = false`

```
$.fancybox.open(
    ['#notifications'],
    {
        autoDimensions: false,
        width : '400',
        closeBtn : false, 
        helpers : {
            overlay : {closeClick: false}
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: `autoDimensions` is not a valid option for fancybox v2.1.x, use `autoSize` instead. Also Boolean and integer values go without quotes so `width : '400'` should be `width : 400`